# Modal from home screen finished displayed when app launched from background

Tags: ios, swift, lifecycle, modalviewcontroller, clean-architecture

### Background

Out app has a feature to launch background using Significant-Change Location Service(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/using_the_significant-change_location_service).

This an iOS feature that when the app detect significant change in location, the app launched on background.  It launches directly to background state so the user won't notice that app has launched(unless writing code to notify to users. ie. sending a local push or etc.) however app is fully launched so didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method on App Delegate is called upon launch.

### Situation

When our app is launched by Significant-Change Location, we send local push notification to the user notifying that how much distance the user has walked recently(we have implemented pedometer to our app).  At this point, our app is launched on background.

A user may tap the local notification just received and then our app's lifecycle state will be changed to foreground and app's home screen will be displayed to the user(from user point of view app is LAUNCHED at this point).

On home view controller, we observe UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification and when detecting this notification, we make an API request.  API response may have an award field(nullable) and when the award is not null, we show the award received modal.

```
// Observe app state changes to active

let center = NotificationCenter.default

center.addObserver(
  self,
  selector: #selector(callRewardAPI), // calls api when detecting notification
  name: UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, // <- didBecomeActiveNotification
  object: nil
)
```

```
func callRewardAPI {
  usecase.callRewardAPI)()
}
```

```
// Show modal when received API response

extension: HomeViewController, HomeUseCaseOutput {
  func didReceiveReward() {
    let vc = RewardReceivedViewController()

    vc.modalTransitionStyle = .crossDissolve
    vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen

    self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

### Problem

#### Expected

We expect to see the modal animation of RewardReceivedViewController.

#### Actual

When the app has finished launching(from user point of view, from application point of view it has been launched on background and moving to foreground), the modal had already been displayed.

We are quite sure that modal had finished displayed upon launch since view displayed on the zoom animation of our app launch(the iOS animation by apple that app's view zooms in to fill the device screen on app launch) shows the modal being displayed.

Something we are confused is that this does not happen all the time but rathe happens several times and then stopped happening(behaving as is should be) for several times.  We checked this on same git commit.

### Something we tried

We tried to simulate the problem by triggering modal display right after receiving UIApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification.

```
func callRewardAPI {

  // Call didReceiveReward right away to show modal.
  self.ouptut.didReceiveReward()

  /*
  self.rewardAPI.request { [weak self] result in
    switch result {
      case .success(let reward):
        self.ouptut.didReceiveReward()
      case .failure:
        // error case
    }
  }
  */
}
```

Since it seems we cannot use Xcode debug breakpoint when simulating app launch from not running to background status, we set local push notification to each point of code to observer what is happening.

What we found out is that code to show modal is called after viewDidAppear.  viewDidAppear is the last lifecycle method of the view controller when launching a view controller so we're stuck finding out the solution.